# Force unsigned type into C++ template typename

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I'm very new in C++ and `template`. I have a template class in C++03 and I want to force the given type always be unsigned. For example:

```
template <typename T>
class Test
{
    T _var1;
};
```

I want to force `T` to be always `unsigned` such as `uint8_t, uint16_t, unsigned int, ...` and fail if the given type is `signed`. Is this possible to do in C++? If so can someone shows how?

Thank you

Comment: Look up the `<type_traits>` header. You'll want to do something with `enable_if`.

Comment: @celticminstrel `enable_if` is most useful for _choosing_ specializations based on conditions and not so much for just enforcing a condition always be true.

Comment: @GuyGreer If you don't define the template base case (declare it but never define it), you can use `enable_if` to only allow instantiation under certain conditions. You do have a point, though - assuming the template should never be instantiated for non-integral types, `static_assert` is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky in C++03 (but easy in C++11).  Boost provides a legible and portable way:

```
#include <limits>
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

template <typename T>
class Test
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer &&
                            !std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed,
                            "T must be an unsigned integer type");
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Specifically, this will fail to compile if those conditions are not statisfied.  I wonder why you didn't put the C++11 solution though, since it would likely be less effort for the OP to enable C++11 then it would be to install boost (assuming that he hasn't already done one of those of course).

Comment: @GuyGreer Unless the OP is in a system/company where they have to stay a particular compiler that doesn't support C++11.

Comment: I'd say it's worth including both versions, since you don't _know_ whether he can use C++11.